# Possible to get sessionStorage data without page refresh

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I'm working on debugging an issue in some existing code that relies on sessionStorage.

The issue looks to be that on initial setting of the storage value, the value isn't available straight away.

Is it possible to set and get a sessionStorage value without refreshing the page first? Can't find anything that says this isn't possible.

This will log undefined:

```
sessionStorage.setItem(
    'foo', 'bar'
);

console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('foo'))
```

But refreshing the page allows the value to be read. Even if I put a timeout around the console log it still returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know where your problem is:

[image]

Maybe your problem is that you set your value async and access it before it is set?

Comment: Fair enough! Looks like the issue lies elsewhere

Comment: Try to find out if you set your value async and access it before it is set

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you're talking about. this works just fine. 
[image]